# Coreos bare metal install login failure, some ignition directives ignored

Tags: coreos, coreos-ignition

I'm a newbie to coreos, and spent the last few days trying to resolve differences between both the obsolete and new documentation in an attempt to figure out how to install coreos on a bare metal system with two network interfaces and four HDDs. I've tried installing several times, but am left with a system that will not let me login from either the console, or remotely through ssh.

Here are the basic steps I've used:

1. Burned coreos version 1800.4.0 ISO image to CD.
2. Created an ignition configuration yaml file, and converted it to json using ct, and put a copy on a USB flash drive.
3. Inserted the flash drive on my bare metal system and booted from the CD ISO.
4. Once the initial system was up, I entered these commands from the console:

   sudo su
   ping google.com  #to verify networking
   lsblk  #to verify my USB flash drive is at: /dev/sde1
   mkdir /mnt/sde1
   mount /dev/sde1 /mnt/sde1
   coreos-install -d /dev/sda -i /mnt/sde1/ignition.json
5. After installation completed, I removed the CD, flash drive, and rebooted.
   reboot

The system booted-up, and displayed a localhost login prompt at the console. Login to the console using the user I specified in the the ignition file fails, it does not accept the password. Logging in remotely from ssh also fails to recognize the password. (The ignition file password_hash value was created using the "openssl passwd -1" command. The ssh_authorized_keys value was creating using the "ssh-keygen -t rsa" command.)

Also, the static network addresses specified in the ignition config was ignored, seems that DHCP was used instead.

Here's my config yaml before being converted to json:

```
# This config is meant to be consumed by the config transpiler, which will
# generate the corresponding Ignition config. Do not pass this config directly
# to instances of Container Linux.

storage:
  files:
    - filesystem: "root"
      path:       "/etc/hostname"
      mode:       0644
      contents:
        inline: coreos1
  disks:
    - device: /dev/sda
      wipe_table: true
      partitions:
       - label: root1
         type_guid: be9067b9-ea49-4f15-b4f6-f36f8c9e1818
         number: 1
         size: 120GiB
       - label: reserve1
         type_guid: a19d880f-05fc-4d3b-a006-743f0f84911e
         number: 2
    - device: /dev/sdb
      wipe_table: true
      partitions:
       - label: root2
         type_guid: be9067b9-ea49-4f15-b4f6-f36f8c9e1818
         number: 1
         size: 120GiB
       - label: reserve2
         type_guid: a19d880f-05fc-4d3b-a006-743f0f84911e
         number: 2
    - device: /dev/sdc
      wipe_table: true
      partitions:
       - label: store1
         type_guid: a19d880f-05fc-4d3b-a006-743f0f84911e
    - device: /dev/sdd
      wipe_table: true
      partitions:
       - label: store2
         type_guid: a19d880f-05fc-4d3b-a006-743f0f84911e
  raid:
    - name: "root_array"
      level: "raid1"
      devices:
        - "/dev/sda1"
        - "/dev/sdb1"
    - name: "reserve_array"
      level: "raid1"
      devices:
        - "/dev/sda2"
        - "/dev/sdb2"
    - name: "store_array"
      level: "raid0"
      devices:
        - "/dev/sdc1"
        - "/dev/sdd1"
  filesystems:
    - name: "ROOT"
      mount:
        device: "/dev/md/root_array"
        format: "ext4"
        label: "ROOT"
    - name: "RESERVE"
      mount:
        device: "/dev/md/reserve_array"
        format: "ext4"
        label: "RESERVE"
    - name: "STORE"
      mount:
        device: "/dev/md/store_array"
        format: "ext4"
        label: "STORE"
networkd:
  units:
    - name: static.network
      contents: |
        [Match]
        Name=eno1
        [Network]
        DNS= *snipped*
        Address=10.0.0.178/24
        Gateway=10.0.0.1
    - name: 00-enp2s0.network
      contents: |
        [Match]
        Name=enp2s0
        [Network]
        DNS= *snipped*
        Address=10.0.0.179/24
        Gateway=10.0.0.1
passwd:
  users:
    - name: "user1"
      password_hash: "$1$Fe8..."
      ssh_authorized_keys:
        - ssh-rsa AAAAB3N...
      groups:
        - "sudo"
        - "docker"
```

After spending another day searching the interwebs for more clues as-to what I've done wrong, I seem to have exausted any other suggestions.

If you have any experience with coreos, please let me know what I may be doing wrong. My goal is to install coreos on bare metal hardware with two network cards and four HDDs in raid arrays, and be able to login at the static address(es) specified.

Comment: I've been trying to do this also for several days. I think that I have discovered the reason but not how to fix it. Apparently, there was a change in how SSH accesses the the keys and where FCOS/Ignition put them. As I understand it FCOS/Ignition writes writes SSH keys to .ssh/authorized_keys.d/ignition file in the user's folder and SSH is looking for them in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file. This is a software killing flaw that seems to have been around since about October of last year. I've spend literally days on this building Ignition files and reinstalling, thinking it was something wrong I wa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI for those finding this question: I finally gave up trying to install coreos on bare metal, it just would not let me login. Switched to basic Ubuntu Server 18.04 and in no-time had my containers running there instead.